# Specifying ocamllex encoding

Tags: ocaml, ocamllex, ocamlyacc

I'm currently developing a parser according to a specification, and I'm completely unable to find [anywhere in the docs](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/lexyacc.html) information about text encoding. It sounds weird to me that the docs of a lexing library wouldn't mention text encoding at all, so I hope I just didn't miss parts of it.

- Does ocamllex force a text encoding?
- If no, how to set which one to use?
- Do ocamllex regexes work with Unicode codepoints internally? Or a specific encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ocamllex works at the byte level and leaves all question of encoding to its users.

More precisely, working at the "byte level" means that ocamllex considers that its input is a sequence of 8-bit words. The ocamllex regex engine then analyzes this sequence of 8-bit words.

Unicode encodings can be seen as a layer of interpretation on the top of this raw sequence of 8 bits words. But the `ocamllex` lexer is unaware of this higher layer of interpretation and just looks at the raw sequence of 8-bit words (which is not that surprising since ocamllex and the first version of unicode were developed around the same time in the beginning of the nineties).
In particular, the graphical character in the lexer are interpreted using their ASCII encoding and thus the character class

```
let digit = ['0'-'9']
```

means one byte in the interval `[0x30, 0x39]`.

If you want a lexer that is aware of unicode character classes and encoding, you can look at [sedlex](https://github.com/ocaml-community/sedlex) .

Comment: "leaves all question of encoding to its users" is just impossible, when a regex engine is embedded inside a lexer. A regex engine _cannot_ work transparently on all encodings. A choice must have been made. Take the lexer `let digit = ['0'-'9']`. How can the digit lexer know if it should read 1, 4, or 2 bytes depending on which encoding you use among UTF-8, UTF-32 or UTF-16?

Comment: Answer edited to precise what `byte level` means.

Comment: OK, thanks for the edit, I understand now. So I guess pretty much all ocamllex-based lexers are only compatible with ASCII supersets (e.g. no UTF-16).

Comment: You can theoretically write an ocamllex lexer to work on UTF-16 encoded unicode input by writing the corresponding byte patterns by hand, but I would be indeed surprised that anyone has done so.